# Changing the mysql default after a certain time period and/or rows are reached?

Tags: php, mysql

I've got an application where for the first 100 rows (think "first 100 customers") I'd like the default of a certain column to be, say, 10.  Then after that promotion is over, I'd like it to be 2.  Is there a way to do that automatically so that I'm not flooded with 1000 rows unexpectedly?

Could I query the number of rows each time a new row is added, then run a SQL statement that would alter the default from 10 to 2 if the mysql_num_rows is over 100?

Answer (score 0):

I try to avoid altering a table schema in code, so how about something like:

1. Leave the default at the permanent value (e.g. 2).
2. Lock the table for insert.*
3. Insert a row.
4. Check the resulting row ID (or however you have set up row counting).
5. If the ID is less than or equal to 100, update the column (e.g. 2 -> 10).
6. Unlock the table.

*: There are alternate ways to do this, such as with transactions, that may be better.  It depends on the volume you are expecting.

Comment: I think this might work but (if I'm understanding it correctly) it looks like this assumes 100 people are already assigned.  I'm hoping for a method that will work before the site launches so that if (wishful thinking) it goes viral then I won't have problems down the line.  Alternately, it might be so slow that I don't check for weeks and then suddenly 50 people sign up.  So any way that will do this automatically will be helpful.  Thanks for your thought though...it's a good solution for sure!

Comment: No, it doesn't make an assumption about there already being 100 people.  Steps 4 and 5 check whether 100 people have been assigned, and if not set your special value.  After 100 people have been assigned, the conditional in step 5 will no longer be true and the normal default (for everyone beyond 100) will be used automatically, which I believe is what you want.